# changing zookeeper routing strategy

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper

our routing strategy used to be `"router":{"name":"compositeId"},`. Something got messeg up and current routing strategy is set to `"router":{"name":"implicit"}},` I want to `purge`  all the records and change routing strategy to `"router":{"name":"compositeId"},`.

Can I simply purge records and change the `ClusterState.json` and it will work fine after that based on `"router":{"name":"compositeId"},` routing strategy. or do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out a while back. Yes, routing strategy can simple be changed from `{"name":"implicit"}` to `"router":{"name":"compositeId"}` as long as you have the range to go with `"router":{"name":"compositeId"}`. In our case, we had 2 other DC which had the ranges defined, we copied the same range for this DC.